# Small sample, many measures

Tags: multiple-comparisons, biostatistics

Suppose you have observations on 50 different measures of joint viability. You have a control sample of 20 individuals not receiving an operation and a sample of 17 individuals before and after the operation. You also have some demographic data on the individuals. There’s a number of simple t-tests that could be run in terms of pre vs control, pre vs post, etc.

And, these tests could be run separately on each of the 50 different measures. Obviously, this gets into the quagmire of multiple comparisons (Bonferroni, etc.), and doesn’t easily summarize the information from the 50 different measures. Is there a way to squeeze more information out of all of these measures?

We can use the control sample to create a “normal” mean and s.d. for each measure and then standardize each individual observation for each measure using those means and s.d’s. We then have about 1,700 observations of measured joint characteristics that are normalized to zero-one and can be treated as a single column of data. Of course, this process is confounded by the lack of independence between the normalized observations (since each person for each group generates 50 of the observations), which biases all of the estimates. Is there any way to salvage this? I can add controls for each subject and each measure – would that make the approach reasonable (and control for demographics for each individual)? Other approaches?